# Display text on textbox based on month selected in datetimepiecker

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello Guys I have a problem with datetimepicker
I am using c# application
I have 1 textbox name texbox1 and 1 datetimepicker name datetimepicker1

my question is
1. how to display text in my textbox if i select the month in datetimepicker
for example i select the month of January there will be number 3 that will display in my textbox if i select February number 98 will display on my textbox and soon......

im working with my assignment

this is my code

```
if(datetimepicker1.Value.Month.ToString() == "January")

{

   textbox1.Text = "3";

}

else if(datetimepicker1.Value.Month.ToString() == "February")

{

   textbox1.Text = "98";

}
```

still no text will display on textbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (datetimepicker1.Value.Date.Month == 3)
   texbox1 .Text = "3";
```

N.B: 3 stands for March, 1 for Jan, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just compare Month with **1** for *Jan* ... **12** for *Dec*?

You can use `ValueChanged` event of `DateTimePicker` class to find out the moment when `DateTimePicker.Value` changes

```
// Whenever dateTimePicker1 Value changed
private void datetimepicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (datetimepicker1.Value.Month == 1) // <- If month is January
    textbox1.Text = "3";
  else if (datetimepicker1.Value.Month == 2) // <- If month is February
    textbox1.Text = "98";
}
```

Since `datetimepicker1.Value.Month` is in fact **integer**, so

```
  datetimepicker1.Value.Month.ToString(); // <- returns "1", not "January"
```